# Kotlin compare button background color

Tags: android, kotlin, background, compare

i need to compare the background color of a button

```
if (button.backgroundColor == Color.GREEN)...
```

but this Code is not working, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
int color = buttonColor.getColor();
if (color == getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue)) {
    // if statement body
}
```

this is the way in java. convert it in kolin